# Property "FilterGroups" does not have accessor method "getFilterGroups"

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, api, rest-api

I'm sending the request

```
http://10.232.32.64/rest/V1/orders?
   searchCriteria[filter_g‌​roups][0][filters][0‌​][field]=status&
   searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=pending&
   searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]‌​=eq
```

to my Magento installation, and I'm getting the error

```
{"message":"Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file.
Report ID: webapi-5c6b179641503"}
```

When I look at my `exception.log`, I see the following error

```
[2019-02-18 20:34:20] main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-5c6b16ccc5482; 
Message: Property "FilterG‌​roups" does not have accessor method 
"getFilterG‌​roups" in class "Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface". 
{"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Report ID: webapi-5c6b16ccc5482; 
Message: Property \"FilterG‌​roups\" does not have accessor method 
\"getFilterG‌​roups\" in class \"Magento\\Framework\\Api\\SearchCriteriaInterface\". 
at /var/www/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:205, 
LogicException(code: 0): Property \"FilterG‌​roups\" does not have accessor method 
\"getFilterG‌​roups\" in class \"Magento\\Framework\\Api\\SearchCriteriaInterface\". 
at /var/www/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Reflection/NameFinder.php:100)"} []
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.  When I copy/pasted the URL from a web page, some weird character must have gotten pasted.  I retyped the URL by hand, and now it works.